# How to put an empty span tag inside an anchor tag with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Hello everybody i have a menu in typoscript and i would like the generated HTML to look 
like this

```
<a href=" ">Text<span></span></a>
```

I am able to wrap Text inside span tags but i cannot find a way to to put an empty span tag
on the right of Text.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty weird to put empty tags on purpose, but here you go:

`HMENU.TMENU.TMENUITEM.stdWrap.wrap = |<span></span>`

For reference, here is the list of wraps you can use for menus:

```
<wrapItemAndSub>
 <allWrap>
 <allStdWrap>
 <before>
 <beforeImg beforeImgTagParams>
 <linkWrap>
  <A href=… ATagParams TITLE=ATagTitle>
   <stdWrap.wrap> TMENUITEM </stdWrap.wrap>
  </A>
 </linkWrap>
 <after>
 </allStdWrap>
 </allWrap>
  UNTERMENU 1
  UNTERMENU 2
</wrapItemAndSub>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I wa tick away from finding the solution i used the whole time stdWrap.wrap = |*|<span></span>. Next time i will read the documentation of optionsplit more carefully :)). They empty span tags will be used for jquery effects ;)

Comment: I guess it's not so wierd to have an empty `<span>` in a tag any more, but at the time you wrote this it probably wasn't as common. For example, Bootstrap 3 uses one in their dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, using `linkWrap` and `ATagBeforeWrap`:

```
menu = HMENU
menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO {
            linkWrap = |<span></span>
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        }
    }
    # ...
}
```